# Database alternative for a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite

I'm building a mobile app that just need to display some datas on a Map. For this I can surely use SQLite and it will make my app much faster.

But I'm concern with some issues such as :

- Will it happens that my db get erased for no real reason ?
- If one day I have more locations an update for the sqlite database pushed to the store will it solve it for me ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: _If one day I have more locations an update for the sqlite database pushed to the store will it solve it for me ?_ what does this mean

Comment: @indramurari I mean if I want to add more data in the sqlite database, knowing that the mobile app is deployed in stores, do I just need to send another version of the database and the user with an update will have those fresh news data ?

Comment: I'm just asking this because if I was using an external database like mysql I won't need any updates because the data to display in the map would come from an API.

Comment: mysql is not for offline usage. also mysql is for server side db and not for client side.. if you want a local database on your device simply create it and query your server for datas

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley you misunderstand me. I didn't said I was going to use MySQL and I know it's for server side. I was talking about SQLite and a proper way to update data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Will it happens that my db get erased for no real reason ?*

No your db will not get erased untill app is uninstalled or app data will be cleared.

*If one day I have more locations an update for the sqlite database pushed to the store will it solve it for me ?*

Use Sqlite if you have static data which will not be changed. Because if you want to change the data you need to update the complete apk which is not recommended.

There are lot of online databases available which sync your data as per your need.

You can use [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) on server and [couchbaselite](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/index.html) for android which does the above mentioned task of syncing

Comment: Ok that enlighten me a lot. So once data are in SQLite it's not possible to change or update it ?

I will have a look at couchbase and other alternatives.

Comment: @lakhassane Yes look for couchbase and couchbase lite. Accept my answer if that helped you